# Phpmyadmin Charsets fatal error 'Undefined index: utf8mb3'

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed a new instance of PHPMyAdmin to work with MySQL8. When accessing the main page I receive an alert with the message:

```
Notice in ./libraries/classes/Charsets.php#154
 Undefined index: utf8mb3

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Controllers/HomeController.php#163: PhpMyAdmin\Charsets::getServerCharset(,
boolean false,)
./libraries/classes/Routing.php#186: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\HomeController->index(array)
./index.php#18: PhpMyAdmin\Routing::callControllerForRoute(
string '/',,,)
```

My MySQL server and client encoding is: utf8.
Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for you, please in future report this issues to our GitHub tracker

See: [issue #16931](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16931)

Here is the official fix: [a2855079abccc05940286424d3017bf8ca9b3c7d](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/a2855079abccc05940286424d3017bf8ca9b3c7d)

Solution: install phpMyAdmin 5.1.1 or newer

Answer (score 4):

## Cause

This seems to be caused by a bug in MySQL 8 when setting `character_set_server` to `utf8` in the MySQL (`[mysqld]`) config.

The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html) states:

> MySQL immediately converts instances of utf8mb3 in statements to utf8,
> so in statements such as SHOW CREATE TABLE or SELECT
> CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS or SELECT
> COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, users see the name
> utf8 or utf8_collation_substring.

However, the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_server';` still returns

```
----------------------+----------+
| Variable_name        | Value   |
+----------------------+---------+
| character_set_server | utf8mb3 |
+----------------------+---------+
```

-> `utf8mb3`

The relevant part of the code in phpMyAdmin can be found in `libraries/classes/Charsets.php`:

```
  /**
  * Get current server charset
  *
  * @param DatabaseInterface $dbi       DatabaseInterface instance
  * @param bool              $disableIs Disable use of INFORMATION_SCHEMA
  */
public static function getServerCharset(DatabaseInterface $dbi, bool $disableIs): Charset
{
    if (self::$serverCharset !== null) {
        return self::$serverCharset;
    }
    self::loadCharsets($dbi, $disableIs);
    $serverCharset = $dbi->getVariable('character_set_server');
    if (! is_string($serverCharset)) {// MySQL 5.7.8 fallback, issue #15614
        $serverCharset = $dbi->fetchValue('SELECT @@character_set_server;');
    }
    self::$serverCharset = self::$charsets[$serverCharset];
    return self::$serverCharset;
}
```

What phpMyAdmin is doing in the method `getServerCharset` in `libraries/classes/Charsets.php` (which is causing the error) is the following:

- It checks whether it has already determined the charset. If not,
- it loads an array of charsets available from the MySQL server with the method `loadCharsets`. This however is done either by the query `SHOW CHARACTER SET;` or by querying `information_schema`. In both cases, `utf8` (instead of `utf8mb3`) is returned, as explained above in the MySQL manual.
- Then, it gets the server charset with the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_server';` (Here, `utf8mb3` is returned as the result, as seen above).
- There is a fallback (not relevant in our case) due to a bug in MySQL 5.7.8, which we can ignore.
- It writes the result into the variable `self::$serverCharset`, by getting the array element with the key `$serverCharset` (which is `utf8mb3`) from the array of all server charsets available . As we know, there is no key `utf8mb3` in the array of the available server charsets (only `utf8` which is the alias for `utf8mb3`). Therefore, the error occurs.

## How to fix it

To fix this, either MySQL should instead return `utf8` on the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_server';`, which isn't something we can easily influence (a bug report might have to be created), or we have to work around it in the phpMyAdmin source code.

To do this, I added

```
if ($serverCharset === "utf8mb3") {
    $serverCharset = "utf8";
}
```

before the line

```
self::$serverCharset = self::$charsets[$serverCharset];
```

so that it now looks like this:

```
  /**
  * Get current server charset
  *
  * @param DatabaseInterface $dbi       DatabaseInterface instance
  * @param bool              $disableIs Disable use of INFORMATION_SCHEMA
  */
public static function getServerCharset(DatabaseInterface $dbi, bool $disableIs): Charset
{
    if (self::$serverCharset !== null) {
        return self::$serverCharset;
    }
    self::loadCharsets($dbi, $disableIs);
    $serverCharset = $dbi->getVariable('character_set_server');
    if (! is_string($serverCharset)) {// MySQL 5.7.8 fallback, issue #15614
        $serverCharset = $dbi->fetchValue('SELECT @@character_set_server;');
    }

    if ($serverCharset === "utf8mb3") {
        $serverCharset = "utf8";
    }

    self::$serverCharset = self::$charsets[$serverCharset];
    return self::$serverCharset;
}
```

The error should not occur anymore.

Comment: Thank you! It fixed the fatal error.
Are you planning to include this fix in a future release?